# Proving Bijection Between $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z _{>0}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that if $\Bbb Z _{>0} \subset \Bbb Z$ is an infinite set, then there exists a bijection f: $\Bbb Z _{>0} \to \Bbb Z$.

Would the Cantor-Bernstein Theorem be applicable in this situation? I'm having trouble conceptualizing the infinite countability of both sets and how that translates to being a bijective function.

Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: $0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,4,-4,\ldots$?

Comment: The notation $\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ usually refers specifically to the positive integers $\{ 1, 2, 3, \dots \}$ and for that set you can write down a bijection very explicitly. Are you referring to that infinite set in particular or any infinite set of integers? If the latter, yes, Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder would work, but there are easier options. You can be pretty explicit about the bijection in this case. (Hint: smallest elements first.)

Comment: The Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem applies but is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  How about $2n\mapsto n, 2n+1\mapsto -n$?  There are certainly others.

Note, this amounts to putting the integers in a list as follows:  $0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,\dots$.